# Detect ethernet connection on Android device pre 3.2

Tags: android, networking, connection, ethernet

In Android 3.2 the TYPE_ETHERNET was added in ConnectivityManager to monitor ethernet network state. Is there a way to detect ethernet connection on pre 3.2 devices?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a broadcast receiver for

```
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

intent in your application.

Here is the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Hope, it help you!

Comment: It will give me the NetworkInfo, but still if it's before 3.2 I can't tell if the network is Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you have the NetworkInfo it would just be if(networkinfo.getType()==9) because the ethernet type is 9.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_ETHERNET